# Why did this command delete every package?

Tags: command-line, linux-mint, apt

I was trying to get a Windows program to run on PlayOnLinux and after it didn't work I went to remove Wine with this command:
        `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*`

and without thinking I agreed to remove every package on the machine. Can someone tell me why it selected every package instead of all the ones starting with the string "wine"?

I'm running Linux Mint 16

Comment: What do you mean by "selected every package"? Did it remove all the packages installed?

Comment: it seemed like there was only the core OS left. all i got was a terminal after rebooting

Comment: Are you sure you didn't type `sudo apt-get remove --purge wine *` accidentally putting a space between `wine` and `*`? Because that would do it.

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie `apt-get remove wine *` would remove all packages whose name is a file in the current directory. In an empty directory, it would error out.

Comment: @Gilles you are making a fair few assumptions about the shell there.

Comment: @WillBoyce I am assuming only that the shell is Bourne-style, csh-style or fish. This is a pretty safe assumption. Except for the part about an empty directory, where `apt-get remove wine *` is equivalent to `apt-get remove wine` in a few cases (bash or zsh with the `nullglob` option).

Answer (score 5):

If there is at least one file in the current directory whose name begins with `wine`, then `wine*` in the command expands to the list of files whose name begin with `wine`. If there is no such file, then

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*
```

is executed. Arguments to `apt-get install` and `apt-get remove` are [extended regular expressions, not shell wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y); `wine*` means `win` followed by any number of `e`, and since this can match any part of the package name, this means any package whose name contains `win` as a substring. Plus, of course, any package that depends on these packages.

If you were using KDE, then you lost the `kde-window-manager` package. If not, you must have lost some other critical package. Maybe `libmate-window-settings1` which is required by `mate-control-center` which is required by `mate-desktop-environment-core` whose loss would render most of the MATE packages superfluous. I checked Debian wheezy package names, Mint might have a different set, but you get the idea.

To remove just the packages whose names start with `wine`, use

```
sudo apt-get purge '^wine'
```

Check the list of packages carefully before confirming.

You may be more comfortable with [Aptitude](https://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude), which has a text mode full screen frontend.