# What are some PRACTICAL scenarios for using the regex + symbol?

Tags: regular-expression

So, I think I know what the RegEx + symbol does (looks for the preceding character 1 or more times). I think I get how to use it...

```
echo "This is a good sentence." | awk '/go+d/ {print $0}'
```

(finds good, gooood, gooooooood)

But, I'm having trouble coming up with a practical, objective reason for wanting to look for this kind of repetition. I need scenarios to give its purpose some context for explanation to others.

Thanks for helping and letting me lean on your knowledge and experiences.

Comment: It makes more sense with digits, as I see it...

Comment: I thought that too, but I couldn't think of a scenario to explain how that would look.

Comment: What about when you want to slurp up whitespace? At least one space, for example. `\s+`. Think about character classes rather than individual characters.

Comment: That is EXACTLY the kind of thing I'm looking for. A great example of why you would use this type of functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking about individual characters when you'll find that `+` is much more useful with character classes...

- Whitespace: `\s+`
- Non-numerical characters: `[^0-9]+`
- A word: `\w+`
- Non-empty string: `.+`
- Etc.

Practical examples should be fairly easy to think of with these. Perhaps I want to find only lines that have indented text: `^\s+\S`. Or I might want to find all non-empty lines: `^.+$`. I can come up with more if you need them. ;)

Comment: No, `[0-9]` is numerical. `[^0-9]` is NOT numerical.

Comment: My bad, I read it as `^[`...

Comment: No worries. I suspected that that's what you saw. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a real-world instance of damage caused by using `*` instead of `+` (mostly because OP didn't realise that they would end up using regexes instead of wildcards): [Why did this command delete every package?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/134291/70524)

> Arguments to `apt-get install` and `apt-get remove` are [extended
>   regular expressions, not shell
>   wildcards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y);
>   `wine*` means `win` followed by any number of `e`, and since this can
>   match any part of the package name, this means any package whose name
>   contains `win` as a substring.

OP had run `sudo apt-get remove wine*`, ended up removing the majority of the installed packages in their system. `wine+`, on the other hand, would have removed packages with `wine` in it.